# Which is the proper style?

Tags: c++, coding-style

Declaring all the variables at the beginning of the code or declaring just before using it,which one is considered as good practice?
like

```
int main(){
int x,y,z,a,b,c;

.....

}
```

or

```
int main()
{
 int x;
 //. ....
 int y,z;
 //......
 int a,b,c;
 //,,....
 }
```

Comment: That's C code, an ancient variety of it.  Still using it makes little sense.

Comment: Stroustrup in his book says that the latter is preferred i.e. defer a variable's declaration until it's going to be used just next. That way even when an exception occurs little needs to be cleaned-up.

Comment: both are ok, but you should use whats more readable, or whats agreed on where you work

Comment: Both are bad. Declare variables once you initialise them, *and not before*. Initialise each variable inside its declaration.

Comment: And make them `const` if it is at all possible to do so.  You'll thank me later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like having all the declarations at the top, each with a comment.  That allows me to go to the same place always.  OTOH (on the other hand) if I want variables to be local to certain area (like `i` as a for loop variable) I break that rule.

Comment: I like waffles.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I like the opposite.

Comment: What's the opposite of a waffle?

Comment: @SteveFallows elffaw.

Comment: `~waffle`, or maybe `1 / waffle`? Even possibly `!waffle`

Comment: As long as we are discussing likes, I like turtles